# php xml with xsd foreach, find out in which block

Tags: php, xml, foreach, xsd

i read out a xml file with xsd, with this code:

```
 foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//caaml:validAspect') as $expositons) {
    echo $xpath->evaluate('string(@xlink:href)', $expositons)."<br>";
 }
```

here i get all results but i can not assign them in which block they are.
and i also tried this:

```
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//caaml:DangerRating') as $dangerRating) {
    echo $xpath->evaluate('string(caaml:validAspect/@xlink:href)', $dangerRating)."<br>";
}
```

here i only get the first value of the validAspect field.

and here is the xml structure:

[image]

and now my problem is that how can i find out in with  block the data is?

Thanks!

now i tried this:

```
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//caaml:DangerRating') as $i => $block) {
  echo "block $i\n";
  foreach ($xpath->evaluate('/caaml:validTime/caaml:validAspect', $block) as $expositions) {
    echo $xpath->evaluate('string(@xlink:href)', $expositons)."<br>";
  }
}
```

but i do not get any result …

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get the block first then the section

```
<?php
$xml = new DOMDocument;
$xml->load("test.xml"); 
$xpath = new DOMXPath($xml);
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//caaml:DangerRating') as $i => $block) {
    echo "block $i\n";
    foreach ($xpath->evaluate('./caaml:validAspect', $block) as $expositions) {
        echo $xpath->evaluate('string(@xlink:href)', $expositions) . "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, but it does not work, the same problem, if i paste your code: $expostions can not be found,

Comment: i tried this:foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//caaml:DangerRating') as $i => $block) {
  echo "block $i\n";

 foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//caaml:validAspect') as $expositons) {
    echo $xpath->evaluate('string(@xlink:href)', $expositons)."<br>";
  }
  
}

Comment: can you provide a sample xml file?

Comment: You iterate `$block` but you use `$expositons` as context for the inner loop.

Comment: tanks for all the answers, i have already tried with $block, i will post the code … here the link to the xml file http://lwdweb.tirol.gv.at/produkte/llb/2013-2014/2014-01-16_0730/2014-01-16_0730_avalanche_bulletin_tyrol_de.xml

Comment: @miholzi, just tested it against the sample xml. it should work now :)

Comment: thanks, but i still get all of the validAspect data from all the blocks,

Comment: @miholzi, ahh. found the problem, changed `//caaml:validAspect` to `./caaml:validAspect` which means only look at the children